# Unterminated String Constant error in Javascript

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, dom-events

I am working on Google Calendar API. Whenever I create any event and enter the description of that event having new line, It gives me error like:

> "Unterminated String constant".

I am passing that Event Description from Java to Javascript. So how to format the string having new line?

My code is:

```
 var EventDescription='<% =eventDetails.getEventDescription(eventIndex)%>'

    eventDetails -java class 
    getEventDEscription -Method to get the Description of event.
    eventIndex - no of the event whoes Description is needed .
```

It is working properly otherwise .only giving error when description is having new line.

Comment: You probably have a mismatch with quotes in your html/javascript generation code in java. Without the code, it's impossible to point it precisely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to imagine yourself as the JSP container, then as the JavaScript interpreter. Or simply look at the source code of the generated HTML page.

The line

```
var EventDescription='<% =eventDetails.getEventDescription(eventIndex)%>'
```

is interpreted by the JSP container. So `eventDetails.getEventDescription(eventIndex)` is executed, and the result of this method call is put in the response. Suppose the result is composed of two lines:

```
line 1
line 2
```

So the generated JavaScript code is:

```
var EventDescription='line1
line 2'
```

And this is invalid JavaScript code. The correct JavaScript code would be

```
var EventDescription='line1\nline 2'
```

So, you need to JavaScript-escape the result of the Java method call before putting it in the response. Look at Apache commons-lang [StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript%28java.lang.String%29) method.